# To send multiple records to salesforce in WSO2 ESB/EI

Tags: json, iterator, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am having multiple records and need to push each records to Salesforce. Can anyone help me to achieve this requirement?

**INPUT REQUEST:**

```
[
   {
      "Lead Source":"LDV Facebook - Book a Test Drive",
      "Preferred Model":"T60 4WD Diesel Dual Cab Ute",
      "Email":"Test1@bigpond.com",
      "Postal Code":"4211",
      "Enquiry Date":"27-03-20",
      "Date Sent":"01-04-20",
      "Mobile":"+61 414 994 774",
      "Name":"Stephen Ross",
      "Dealer":"QLD -Von Bibra Gold Coast - 554216"
   },
   {
      "Lead Source":"LDV i-Motor - Get a Quote",
      "Preferred Model":"T60 4WD Diesel Dual Cab Ute",
      "Email":"Test2@gmail.com",
      "Postal Code":"4209",
      "Enquiry Date":"27-03-20",
      "Date Sent":"01-04-20",
      "Mobile":"+61 423 927 999",
      "Name":"Jaxon",
      "Dealer":"QLD - Von Bibra Gold Coast - 554216"
   },
   {
      "Lead Source":"LDV i-Motor - Get a Quote",
      "Preferred Model":"T60 4WD Diesel Dual Cab Ute",
      "Email":"Test3@hotmail.com",
      "Postal Code":"4209",
      "Enquiry Date":"28-03-20",
      "Date Sent":"01-04-20",
      "Mobile":"+61 447809 834",
      "Name":"Brendan Dunleavy",
      "Dealer":"QLD - Von Bibra Gold Coast - 554216"
   }
]
```

**Proxy Code:**

```
 <iterate expression="//jsonArray/jsonElement" id="LDVid" sequential="true">
                    <target>
                        <sequence>
                            <property description="incomingRequest" expression="$body/*" name="incomingRequest" scope="default" type="OM"/>
                            <!-- Business  process related sequence -->
                            <sequence key="ProcessSequence"/>
                        </sequence>
                    </target>
                </iterate>
```

**Note**:

- Inside **ProcessSequence** need to fetch each json object element,because business related operation is there for json element.
- Using Salesforce Rest Connector each records will be pushed to Salesforce using Call Mediator.
- Aggregate operation needed after iterator.

Here i can't able to fetch each json element by below technique.

```
<property description="Email" expression="$ctx:incomingRequest//*[local-name()='Email']/text()" name="Email" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
```

Comment: Can you log the body inside the ProcessSequence and share i here? <log level="custom">
    <property name="BODY"
              expression="$body"/>
</log>

Comment: Hi @ArunanSugunakumar,
I can able to get jsonbody inside sequence as well. now i fetched json element like below.<property description="Lead Source" expression="//*[local-name()='Lead Source']/text()" name="LeadSource" scope="default" type="STRING"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I met my requirement, now i can send multiple records to Salesforce one by one by using Iterator.

```
<iterate expression="//jsonArray/jsonElement" id="LDVid" sequential="true">
                    <target>
                        <sequence>
                            <sequence description="ProcessSequence" key="ProcessSequence"/>
                        </sequence>
                    </target>
                </iterate>
                <property name="Aggregated_Responses" scope="default">
                    <jsonObject/>
                </property>
                <aggregate id="LDVid">
                    <completeCondition>
                        <messageCount max="-1" min="-1"/>
                    </completeCondition>
                    <onComplete enclosingElementProperty="Aggregated_Responses" expression="$body/*[1]" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd">
                        <log description="***aggregated***" separator="***aggregated***">
                            <property expression="$ctx:Aggregated_Responses" name="Aggregated_Responses"/>
                        </log>
                        <send/>
                    </onComplete>
                </aggregate>
```